# consistency of large cardinal axiom

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

It is known that if ZFC is consistent, ZFC+"no such large cardinal exists" is consistent. Then, is ZFC+"such large cardinal exists" known to be consistent? This would imply that proving large cardinal axiom is independent from ZFC...

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ZFC cannot prove its own consistency, this is a result due to Godel's incompleteness theorems.

If, however, $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal then $V_\kappa$ which is the collection of all sets whose von Neumann rank is $<\kappa$ is a model of ZFC. Due to the completeness theorem of Godel, this implies that ZFC *is* consistent.

So we cannot prove the existence of an inaccessible cardinal in ZFC.

Furthermore, suppose ZFC+There is an inaccessible cardinal is consistent, let $\kappa$ be the *least* inaccessible cardinal, then $V_\kappa$ is a model of ZFC but there are no inaccessible in $V_\kappa$.

(and almost all large cardinals are inaccessible, and if they are not inaccessible they imply that below them there are inaccessible cardinals, it might be that a cardinal is *weakly* inaccessible but "going down" to $L$ makes it a strongly inaccessible, and we are only interested in consistency results anyway)